# The fastest large queue mechanism for read/write

Tags: java, performance, queue

I need a system that writes sequentially, very fast to a synchronized persistent queue and reads very fast from it. The queue can spike and grow to hundred of millions, possible billions of entries on certain days and it could take days to catchup afterwards, which is fine.

I'm thinking of something like this:

Receiving multiple requests containing numbers 0-4 (order doesn't matter)

```
Queue[10]: [ 0 1 2 3 4 _ _ _ _ _ ]
```

The queue is also written to a file (f0) concomitant to being submitted to the queue. The reason for this is so in case of failures I'm not loosing data.

While I'm reading from it in sequence (0, 1, 2) more numbers are posted:

```
Queue[10]: [ _ _ _ 3 4 5 6 7 _ _ ]
```

At this point my file f0 contains (0-7) and I have also persisted the last position read.

If I'm continuing to write and the current queue gets full, the next 10 writes go directly into  a file f1. The next 10 will go into f2 and so on. When the reading finished reading all entries from the queue f1 will be loaded into the queue and the reading will continue. f0 will be deleted. When my reads catch up with the writes the current file will be read into the queue and will continue from that point.

I can probably provide a better implementation by using a primary/secondary buffer.

However I would prefer to use an existing library if there is one that does what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sebi

Comment: Read paper on persistent queues: http://www.cs.gonzaga.edu/~bowers/papers/swf-2011.pdf

Comment: Excellent. The "Fast-tracked Persistent Queue" is close to what I had in mind. Any open source implementations of this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what hardware you'll be implementing this on. Spikes of 1billion entries in a day would require 11k transactions a second for 24hrs. How large is the data/items you are adding to the queue?

Comment: @LastCoder the items are small ~90b on average. I plan to use a "Large Instance" and upgrade to the  "Extra Large Instance" or "Cluster Compute Eight Extra Large Instance" if needed. The max I expect based on current throughput and forecasted growth is 19K requests/s for a few days a year. Otherwise, 2-3K r/s on an average day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a library which supports a persisted queue which can support 5 - 20 million entires per second sustained and can have number of entires between the single producer and multiple consumers (they don't even have to be running at the same time)  It doesn't carry any GC overhead.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

The library requires 64-bit JVM if you want much scalability and it is limited by the amount of disk space you have.

The library assumes you will cycle the files used as a maintenance task.  This requires you have sufficient disk space to cover the period between maintenance windows.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have seen your library before in a different context. In this case it might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Do you have any design document that shows how it works? It would be really helpful when evaluating it, especially understanding the implications of the design from a performance point of view.

Comment: The closest page is http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/ultra-low-latency-event-store.html which doesn't cover much of the details.  I need to add a How It Works page. Is there anything you need to know in particular?

Comment: Hi Peter, in my case I will have a few hundred threads concomitantly writing to the queue text entries that average 90 bytes (70-110bytes). That adds up to 19000 request/s sending 1.7 Mb/s. My requirements are quite relaxed here - I need to write as fast as possible and do not care if in the case of a failure the last few items are lost. Then I have 5-10 threads reading from the queue to process the data. Each read will pop N entries from the queue, and process it. 
Can I delete the entry when reading it from queue?

Comment: Is the queue maintained as a queue on the disk with disk pointers and pages? Is it a circular queue initially ? Does it get fragmented when you resize it? Is the queue transactional? Can it get corrupted? If yes, how to recover? Thanks.

Comment: 19K message per second isn't that much but hundreds of writers is a bit surprising, are these client connection threads?  In that case I have used synchronization to write only one message at a time.

Comment: Provided the OS doesn't crash, all messages are preserved. There is no particular need to process the entires in batches but you can do if you wish. You can't delete entries, they just accumulate. This means you could create GBs over a day.

Comment: There an index file and a data file. The index file determine where the message are and the data file the contents. Its not circular which means it can grown to the size of your disk space. It doesn't get fragmented and it can't get corrupted easily. It will get corrupted if multiple threads update the file at once. You have to prevent this.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. The fragmentation and more serious corruption I was hinting to happen in the case where the system allows you to delete the entries read from the queue.

Comment: Which why I don't allow deletion. If you write 1.7 MB/s constantly for 6.8 days it will use about 1 TB of disk space. This is enough to run for a week and cycle the files so you can run for another week.